# How to access encrypted samba share?

Tags: server, 20.04, samba, encryption

I have a home file and print server running samba on Ubuntu 20.04 Server.

I would like to encrypt traffic between clients and the server. My understanding from man smb.conf is that this is done by setting [global] smb encrypt = required in /etc/samba/smb.conf.

However, when I do this I cannot access my shares from a client on the local network running Ubuntu 20.04.3 Desktop. The error it returns is "Oops! Something went wrong. Don't have permission to access the requested location." In addition, if I try to use smbclient on the client it returns the following error:

```
~$ smbclient -L ip.of.server -U my_user_name
Enter WORKGROUP\my_user_name's password:
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Commenting out the line and restarting samba fixes both problems.

What additional configuration is needed (server or client side) to be able to access an encrypted samba share?

Thank you.

======

To capture the solution here: I had set max protocol = SMB2 on the server. Commenting out that line fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMB encryption requires SMB protocol version 3. (*)
Try adding the option `--max-protocol=SMB3_11` to your `smbclient` command to see whether that is the cause of the problem.
Also add the option `--debuglevel=1` to make `smbclient` tell you a bit more about what it is doing and where it goes wrong.

(*) Neglecting Samba SMBv1 encryption which shouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it. I had set max protocol = SMB2 on the server. My note says this is to be nice to Windows clients, though I cannot now remember what the problem was. Commenting out that line fixed it. Now I may have a Windows access issue to troubleshoot, but that is a separate question.